# Trying to find specific JS Chart with two different X axis

Tags: javascript, charts

I try to found some JS library, who can help me create chart like on coinglass: https://www.coinglass.com/BitfinexMargin

[image]

I have same task with two different X-axis, where first X-axis if base price of my product, second X-axis number of sales in time.

I have checked these libraries:

- https://dygraphs.com/
- https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/
- https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/
- https://plotly.com/javascript
- https://recharts.org/en-US/examples
- https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery
- https://www.chartjs.org/
- https://www.highcharts.com/

But no one helps me...

May be you know ? ^_^

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out what charting library that site is using? When you inspect the coinglass chart's element, you'll see it has a class `echarts-for-react`, so it's safe to assume they use Apache ECharts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Highcharts to generate a multi axis chart, also you can check this [link](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10921), it is a bit old but can be useful, or this demo (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes), I made this example, I think it is similar to what you are trying to do.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Product Sales'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Price 1', 'Price 2', 'Price 3', 'Price 4', 'Price 5'],
        crosshair: true
    }, {
        categories: ['Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 4', 'Day 5'],
        opposite: true,
        linkedTo: 0,
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value} units',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Sales',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'Price',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '${value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Price',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Sales',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [100, 200, 150, 300, 250],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' units'
        }
    }]
});
```

[Link Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d35a8kct/)